# JTree: won't redisplay new model

Tags: java, swing, jtree

When I start my Java swing application, I read an XML file into a DefaultTreeModel, create a new JTree with the model, add the jtree to a JScrollPane, and Life is Good.  Everything works:

```
// Program initialization:
jarFilesDB = new JarFilesDB ();
jarFilesDB.load(JarFilesDB.JAR_DB_FILENAME);
jtree = new JTree(jarFilesDB.getRootNode ());
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane (jtree);
contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Later on, I might want to create a *new* XML file, and completely rebuild my model.  When I do this, I can't get the jtree to redisplay the new model.  Either I get a blank pane, or the old model still displays:

```
// Completely regenerate XML file and Model
jarFilesDB.mkXmlFile (sPath);                // Generate new XML file
jarFilesDB.load(JarFilesDB.JAR_DB_FILENAME); // Generate new Model
```

Per Andrew Thompson's request, I wrote a "Short (as possible), Self-Contained, Correct (not! or I wouldn't be asking the question) Example):

```
package com.rgb;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class FrmMain extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FrmMain frame = new FrmMain();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public FrmMain() {
        setTitle("HelloJTree3");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Click Me");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                doClick ();
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jarFilesDB = new JarFilesDB ();
        jarFilesDB.load(isAlpha);
        isAlpha = !isAlpha;
        jtree = new JTree(jarFilesDB.getRootNode ());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane (jtree);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);   
    }

    private void doClick () {
        jarFilesDB.load(isAlpha);
        isAlpha = !isAlpha;
    }

    private JarFilesDB jarFilesDB;
    private JTree jtree;
    private boolean isAlpha = false;
}

class JarFilesDB extends DefaultTreeModel {

    public JarFilesDB () {
        super (null);
    }

    public void load (boolean isAlpha) {
        if (rootNode == null)
            rootNode =  new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
        else
            rootNode.removeAllChildren ();

        String[] values;
        if (isAlpha)
            values = new String[] {"A", "A1", "A2", "B", "B1", "B2"};
        else
            values = new String[] {"10", "11", "12", "20", "21", "22"};

        DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode (values[0]);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode leafNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode (values[1]);
        childNode.add(leafNode);
        leafNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode (values[2]);
        childNode.add(leafNode);
        rootNode.add(childNode);

        childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode (values[3]);
        leafNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode (values[4]);
        childNode.add(leafNode);
        leafNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode (values[5]);
        childNode.add(leafNode);
        rootNode.add(childNode);
    }

    public TreeNode getRootNode () {
        return rootNode;
    }

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = null;

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Why dont you use `jtree.setModel(jarFilesDB);` when you initialize the tree?

Comment: @Max - class jarFilesDB inherits from DefaultTreeModel.  I don't need a "setModel()" initially because I just use the root node of the model as the constructor for the jtree.  The response you deleted is correct: I *shouldn't* need either removeAll() or setModel().  Any suggestions would definitely be appreciated :) Thanx in advance...

Comment: @paulsm4 , In the above code, during the initialization, the tree creates its own `DefaulTreeModel` with the provided root node. Later, during update you feed it your implementation. Just to make sure your model is properly implemented use it when you initialize the tree and see that you get correct results. Then test it with updates. You can also do it vice versa of course :)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - I added an "SSCCE" to reproduce the problem.  The jtree only shows the first model ("numeric"), no matter how many times I change it.  I'm sure the problem is something simple - please let me know what you think!

Comment: +1 for posting SSCCE :) good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add()` methods don't fire updates. It is best to use `insertNodeInto`. To fix, add the following:

```
nodeStructureChanged(rootNode);
```

At the end of `load()` method.

And use this to initialize the tree:

```
jtree = new JTree(jarFilesDB);
```

Here's the updated SSCCE, not sure what is the intent for `rootNode`, so I left it alone:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class FrmMain extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FrmMain frame = new FrmMain();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public FrmMain() {
        setTitle("HelloJTree3");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Click Me");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                doClick ();
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jarFilesDB = new JarFilesDB ();
        jarFilesDB.load(isAlpha);
        isAlpha = !isAlpha;
        //jtree = new JTree(jarFilesDB.getRootNode ());
        jtree = new JTree(jarFilesDB);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane (jtree);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    }

    private void doClick () {
        jarFilesDB.load(isAlpha);
        isAlpha = !isAlpha;
    }

    private JarFilesDB jarFilesDB;
    private JTree jtree;
    private boolean isAlpha = false;
}

class JarFilesDB extends DefaultTreeModel {

    public JarFilesDB () {
        super (new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root"));
        rootNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) getRoot(); 
    }

    public void load (boolean isAlpha) {
        rootNode.removeAllChildren ();

        String[] values;
        if (isAlpha)
            values = new String[] {"A", "A1", "A2", "B", "B1", "B2"};
        else
            values = new String[] {"10", "11", "12", "20", "21", "22"};

        DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode (values[0]);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode leafNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode (values[1]);
        childNode.add(leafNode);
        leafNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode (values[2]);
        childNode.add(leafNode);

        rootNode.add(childNode);

        childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode (values[3]);
        leafNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode (values[4]);
        childNode.add(leafNode);
        leafNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode (values[5]);
        childNode.add(leafNode);
        rootNode.add(childNode);

        nodeStructureChanged(rootNode);
    }

    public TreeNode getRootNode () {
        return rootNode;
    }

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = null;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can just use `JTree.updateUI()`